# How to show slug on HTML id in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to get the id to have slug such that i could get id="the_title" if the title is the title. Such that i could use custom css n js things to only specific post.
I can do it using Php but i want to know if there is Wordpress specific code that could do it in a word or two.  like

```
the_title()
```

Here is where i want to do that

```
<h3 class= "serviceslist" id="What to put here to get the post's slug"><?php the_title(); ?> : <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in function for displaying a slug.  However, you can get it from the global $post object:

```
<h3 class= "serviceslist" id="<?php echo $post->post_name ?>">
    <?php the_title() ?> : <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
</h3>
```